# NavigationView and AutoSuggestbox not suggesting NavigationViewItems UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I've stuck on the problem with matching phrases with Property value "Content" of NavigationViewItem. My app is pretty large, so I made a sample view for the sake of this post.

This is my XAML View Code

```
<Page
    x:Class="testowa.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:testowa"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:rg="using:SourceChord.ResponsiveGrid"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    muxc:BackdropMaterial.ApplyToRootOrPageBackground="True">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!--This top margin is the height of the custom TitleBar-->
        <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="AppTitleBar"
                IsHitTestVisible="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="Transparent"
                Height="40"
                Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
                Margin="48,8,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="AppFontIcon"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="Assets/Square44x44Logo.png" 
                    Width="16" 
                    Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle"
                    Text="Aplikacja Szpitalna"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="12, 0, 0, 0"
                    Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl"
            IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"            
            IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"           
            DisplayModeChanged="NavigationViewControl_DisplayModeChanged"   
            Canvas.ZIndex="0">
            <muxc:NavigationView.Header>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Dashboard" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
                </Grid>
            </muxc:NavigationView.Header>
            <muxc:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
                <AutoSuggestBox 
                    PlaceholderText="Wyszukaj" 
                    QueryIcon="Find"                     
                    x:Name="controlsSearchBox"
                    TextChanged="ControlsSearchBox_TextChanged"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    KeyboardAcceleratorPlacementMode="Hidden">
                </AutoSuggestBox>
            </muxc:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItemSeparator />
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Menu Główne"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItemSeparator />
                <!--Sekcja techniczna-->
                <muxc:NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Techniczne" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="List" Content="System Kolejkowy"/>

                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="FourBars" Content="Networking">
                    <muxc:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Serwery" Icon="AllApps"/>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Urządzenia aktywne" Icon="Manage"/>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Punkty PPD" Icon="Map"/>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Adresy IP" Icon="GoToStart"/>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Dostęp zdalny" Icon="Globe"/>
                        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Skaner ARP" Icon="Find"/>
                    </muxc:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
            </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </muxc:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is Event Method binded to AutoSuggestBox

```
private void ControlsSearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Pobierz tekst z elementu AutoSuggestBox
    string searchText = sender.Text;

    // Filtruj elementy menu nawigacyjnego za pomocą pobranego tekstu
    var filteredMenuItems = NavigationViewControl.MenuItems
        .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
        .Where(item => item.Content.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant()))
        .ToList();

    // Ustaw wynik filtrowania jako elementy sugestii dla elementu AutoSuggestBox
    sender.ItemsSource = filteredMenuItems;
}
```

Nothing happens, Debug.WriteLine shows 0 elements in filteredMenuItems. I've been looking the solution for days. Checked Learn.Microsoft, sample Github projects.

I'm expecting the code shows NavigationViewItems which match the phrase with Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not only `NavigationViewItem` in the `NavigationViewControl.MenuItems`, but also `NavigationViewItemSeparator` and `NavigationViewItemHeader` in it.

Please try the following code:

```
    public List<string> CheckItems( List<object> sourceList, List<string> resultList, string searchText) 
    {
        foreach (var item in sourceList)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(MUXC.NavigationViewItem))
            {
                // get first level item
                MUXC.NavigationViewItem viewItem = item as MUXC.NavigationViewItem;

                //check if contains second level items

                List<object> level2Items = viewItem.MenuItems.ToList();

                if (level2Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    CheckItems(level2Items,resultList,searchText);
                }
                else
                {
                    // this is the first level item
                    var str = viewItem.Content.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
                    if (str.Contains(searchText))
                    {
                        resultList.Add(viewItem.Content.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    private void controlsSearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        string searchText = sender.Text;

        List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

        List<object> itemlist = NavigationViewControl.MenuItems.ToList();

        CheckItems(itemlist, resultList, searchText);

        sender.ItemsSource = resultList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you another option that switches the `Visibility` of each item.

```cs
private void ControlsSearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    string filter = sender.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

    foreach (object item in this.NavigationViewControl.MenuItems)
    {
        MakeVisibleItemsThatMatchFilter(parent: null, child: item, filter);
    }
}

private void MakeVisibleItemsThatMatchFilter(NavigationViewItem? parent, object child, string filter)
{
    if (child is NavigationViewItem childNavigationViewItem)
    {
        if (childNavigationViewItem.Content is string content &&
            content.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter) is true)
        {
            childNavigationViewItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            if (parent is not null)
            {
                parent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                parent.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            childNavigationViewItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        foreach (object grandChild in childNavigationViewItem.MenuItems)
        {
            MakeVisibleItemsThatMatchFilter(childNavigationViewItem, grandChild, filter);
        }
    }
    else if (child is UIElement childUIElement)
    {
        childUIElement.Visibility = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) is true
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```